# How to write Hg mercurial commit message with space tab and korean?

Tags: mercurial

I'm using  Hg mercurial 2.8.2.

My problem is about commit message when I commit using command line.

Like "hg ci -m 'my test 가나다'" , mercurial rejects commit (space tab and Korean).

How can I solve this problem? Do I have to re-install with another version?

If I have to revise specific config file, please let me know where it is.

(ps, My platform is 'Win7 - 64bit')

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "space tab"?

Comment: That means 'word spacing'.

Comment: Use `hg ci -m "my test가나다"`.  Note double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `HGENCODING` system environment variable to `utf-8`

To do that open Windows Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables

Add New variable and enter following values:

- Variable name `HGENCODING`
- Variable value `utf-8`

Additional links about encoding issue:

- [Mercurial Encoding Strategy](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EncodingStrategy)
- [Mercurial Character Encoding on Windows](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CharacterEncodingOnWindows)

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, it works but word spacing still not working. I'll find more solution with your references. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @volt772 Have you tried using GUI client. I made successful commit with your demo message (I don't know Korean, so I cannot tell if it is exactly what you want) using TortoiseHG. It is fast and simple to use http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/ and it has command window where you can also use commands like you are used to in command line.

Comment: I also use GUI Program named SourceTree, But I usually using command line. SourceTree has no problem about Korean and word spacing.

Comment: @volt772 I am also using SourceTree, but TortoiseHg is much faster so I prefer it. I rarely use command line or I use it from TortoiseHg.